# What does Pr(>Chisq) stand for?

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am currently writing a report from the summary screen of a Linear Mixed Modeling and trying to reference a value of "<2e-16" under Pr(>Chisq) under Fixed Effects.

What is the name of this column? In other words, if I were to write without using the "Pr(>Chisq)" symbol, what else can I call it?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the p-value.

More technically, it's the probability of obtaining a chi-squared value greater than the one shown, under the null hypothesis, hence `Pr(>Chisq)`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! What a wonderful space I finally got a clear answer!! THANK YOU SO MUCH, Eoin!!

Answer (score 0):

Pr > ChiSq is a Chi-square test statistic. Associated p-value (Pr > ChiSq) corresponds to the specific test that all of the predictors are simultaneously equal to zero. You can test the probability of Pr>ChiSq of observing a Chi-Square statistic as extreme, or more so, than the observed one under the null hypothesis. The null hypothesis is that all of the regression coefficients in the model are equal to zero. Pr > ChiSq is compared to a specified alpha level, our willingness to accept a type I error, which is often set at 0.05 or 0.01. The small p-value from all three tests would conclude that at least one of the regression coefficients in the model is not equal to zero. [1]

Here is an example in R using `chisel.test` on `mtcars` dataset:

```r
chisq.test(mtcars$carb, mtcars$cyl)
#> Warning in chisq.test(mtcars$carb, mtcars$cyl): Chi-squared approximation may be
#> incorrect
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  mtcars$carb and mtcars$cyl
#> X-squared = 24.389, df = 10, p-value = 0.006632
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The result shows a high ChiSq value and a p-value less than 0.05. So you can reject the null hypothesis and conclude in this case that the columns carb and cyl have a significant relationship. [2]

---

Sources:

- [PROC LOGISTIC|SAS ANNOTATED OUTPUT](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/output/proc-logistic/) [1]
- [Chi-Square test in R](https://data-flair.training/blogs/chi-square-test-in-r/) [2]

Comment: Thank you for your response Quinten!!! I appreciate that you provided such a detailed response! I am carefully reading through and trying to understand the concept (I am very new to R). Thanks to you I am starting to like stats altogether!! :)